# High Precision Log Time for Chef Logs

Tags: bash, chef-infra, chef-recipe

I am starting to work with chefserver. I want to get some calculation from the logs of chefserver. However, the time stamp is displayed without milliseconds. In order to get more precise calculation I want the logs of the recipes to have milliseconds.

The logs are in the following format:

```
[2017-08-29T18:44:22+00:00] INFO: bash[dummyResource] ran successfully
```

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

You can change the formatter in your `client.rb` (or in cookbook library code but then it would only affect things after that code runs):

```
Chef::Log.logger.formatter = whatever
```

https://github.com/chef/mixlib-log/blob/master/lib/mixlib/log/formatter.rb shows the default formatter, you can subclass and tweak as you desire.